# How to Create Lollipop with descending order

Tags: ggplot2

I am trying to create a lollipop graph with bars in descending order. I have tried reordering the bars but it is not working. Any idea where my mistake is located?

```
 # Horizontal Lollipop Chart with Ball on Right Side and Data
 library(ggplot2)
 library(dplyr)

 df <- data.frame(category = c("To save more money", 
                          "To exercise more", 
                          "To eat healthier", 
                          "To spend more time with family/friends",
                          "To lose weight", 
                          "To reduce spendings on living expenses (e.g., food,       energy)",
                          "To spend less time on social media",
                          "To reduce stress on the job"),
             value = c(59, 50, 47, 40, 35, 26, 19, 19))

   # Arrange the data frame in descending order
   dm <- df %>% arrange(desc(value))

  # Create the lollipop chart
  ggplot(dm, aes(x = reorder(category, value), y = value, label = value)) +
  geom_segment(
   aes(x = category, y = 0, xend = category, yend = value), 
   color = "steelblue", 
   linewidth = 1.5
    ) +
    geom_point(aes(x = category, y = value), color = "steelblue", size = 4) +
    geom_text(
    aes(label = paste0(value, "%")),
    hjust = -0.75, 
    vjust = 0.5, 
    color = "black",
    size = 3
     ) + 
   theme_minimal() +
   theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank()) + 
   coord_flip() +   
   labs(title = "Horizontal Lollipop Chart", x = "", y = "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are re-mapping the x-axis aesthetics in `geom_segment` and `geom_point`, effectively overriding the reordering you aimed for in the top `ggplot()` call.

One way to handle this is to reorder the `category` factor levels in the data frame directly.

##### Setup

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


df <- data.frame(category = c("To save more money", 
                              "To exercise more", 
                              "To eat healthier", 
                              "To spend more time with family/friends",
                              "To lose weight", 
                              "To reduce spendings on living expenses (e.g., food,       energy)",
                              "To spend less time on social media",
                              "To reduce stress on the job"),
                 value = c(59, 50, 47, 40, 35, 26, 19, 19))
```

##### Factor levels before and after reordering

```r
levels(factor(df$category)) 
#> [1] "To eat healthier"                                                 
#> [2] "To exercise more"                                                 
#> [3] "To lose weight"                                                   
#> [4] "To reduce spendings on living expenses (e.g., food,       energy)"
#> [5] "To reduce stress on the job"                                      
#> [6] "To save more money"                                               
#> [7] "To spend less time on social media"                               
#> [8] "To spend more time with family/friends"

dm <- df %>%
  mutate(category = forcats::fct_reorder(factor(category), value))

levels(factor(dm$category))
#> [1] "To reduce stress on the job"                                      
#> [2] "To spend less time on social media"                               
#> [3] "To reduce spendings on living expenses (e.g., food,       energy)"
#> [4] "To lose weight"                                                   
#> [5] "To spend more time with family/friends"                           
#> [6] "To eat healthier"                                                 
#> [7] "To exercise more"                                                 
#> [8] "To save more money"
```

##### Plotting

```r
# Create the lollipop chart
ggplot(dm, aes(x = category, y = value, label = value)) +
  geom_segment(
    aes(x = category, y = 0, xend = category, yend = value), 
    color = "steelblue", 
    linewidth = 1.5
  ) +
  geom_point(aes(x = category, y = value), color = "steelblue", size = 4) +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = paste0(value, "%")),
    hjust = -0.75, 
    vjust = 0.5, 
    color = "black",
    size = 3
  ) + 
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank()) + 
  coord_flip() +   
  labs(title = "Horizontal Lollipop Chart", x = "", y = "")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>